# Unable to get whole table data while fetching from website

Tags: java, pagination, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch data from a website, but that table having multiple pages having page navigation like 1 |2 | 3..., but I am trying to get whole table data by using following code but it is giving only first page data:

```
WebResponse response = getResponse(URLStr,wc);
    WebTable table = response.getTableWithID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grd1");

    String[] dataRows = new String[table.getRowCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        dataRows[i]  = table.getRows()[i].getText().replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println("recored "  +  table.getRows()[i].getText());

    }
```

How to get all pages data of the table instead of just one?

Comment: The only way to get all the rows is to call the web page with different parameters (i.e. parameters corresponding to page 1, page 2, page 3 etc so this will require multiple server requests. This may or may not be easy (though it 's probably easy if it's a simple GET request. You can 't get all the rows in one go unless you have direct access to the database, which you don't have.

Comment: but that table having more than 100 pages

Comment: There's no way around it, I'm afraid.